transitive edges in APL
Say we have a rank 2 vector that represents edges in a graph:
      m←3 2⍴3 5 5 9 6 3
      m
3 5
5 9
6 3

And we want to compute the transitive edges.
e.g. Since we have the edge from node 3 to 5 and the edge from node 5 to 9 then transitively we also have the edge from node 3 to 9.
I have implemented a function to do that like this:
transitive_edges_one_step←{idx←⍸⍵[;2]∘.=⍵[;1] ⋄ 0=⍴idx:⍵ ⋄ ∪⍵⍪↑⍵∘{⍺[1⌷⍵;1],⍺[2⌷⍵;2]}¨idx}

Running it 'till quiescence produces the desired result:
      (transitive_edges_one_step⍣≡) m
3 5
5 9
6 3
3 9
6 5
6 9

What are some more terse solutions?
Does this problem require a recursive approach (here with the power operator)?
Also, for larger rank 2 vectors (20,000 rows) I get WS FULL in Dyalog. Are there solutions that use less memory?

Before I can give a better algorithm, note that Dyalog APL does not dynamically allocate additional workspace when the predetermined limited has been used up. The MAXWS init parameter controls the limit, the default is 256M, and you may want to check Installation Guide of the corresponding platform for how to change that. In practice Dyalog should be able to handle a very large workspace up to serval TBs.

Here's a shorter and more efficient version of B. Wilson's answer:
First, the adjacency matrix is computed simply by checking which of all possible edges exist in the list of edges:
      ⎕←a←(↓∊⍨∘⍳2⍴⌈⌿∘,)m
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Then we compute the transitive closure of that using Boolean functions instead of arithmetic ones:
      ⎕←e←(∨.∧⍨∨⊢)⍣≡a
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Finally, as in the original, we get the indices of the edges:
      ↑⍸e
3 5
3 9
5 9
6 3
6 5
6 9

This is brief enough that we can put it all together in a single line:
      ↑⍸(∨.∧⍨∨⊢)⍣≡(↓∊⍨∘⍳2⍴⌈⌿∘,)m
3 5
3 9
5 9
6 3
6 5
6 9

We can even define this as a function:
      TE←↑∘⍸(∨.∧⍨∨⊢)⍣≡∘(↓∊⍨∘⍳2⍴⌈⌿∘,)
      TE m
3 5
3 9
5 9
6 3
6 5
6 9

Try it online!

The power series of the adjacency matrix gives the transitive closure:
      a←{(2⍴1+⌈⌿,⍵)↑⍸⍣¯1↓⍵}m  ⍝ Adjacency matrix
      ↑⍸(×⊢+a+.×⊢)⍣≡a
 3 5
 3 9
 5 9
 6 3
 6 5
 6 9

Granted, memory usage is quadratic in node count.

Adam's solution showcases the classic transitive closure idiom in APL. I just want to share some more excellent write ups by Roger Hui around this, which also includes an implementation using lists instead of a matrix (more efficient if your graph is sparse)
https://forums.dyalog.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1376&hilit=transitive+closure
https://forums.dyalog.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=1636&p=6468

In Roger's "solution using lists" (adjacency list representation) he references a variable b that I don't see defined anywhere. Do you see what he meant by that?

An only slightly better answer:
    z←{∪⍵⍪↑⊃,/f,¨¨t((t←⊢/⍵)/⍨⊢)⍤=¨⊂f←⊣/⍵}
    z⍣≡⊢ m
3 5
5 9
6 3
3 9
6 5
6 9

